# Juntar um monte de selects em um só

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Tenho 4 selects pra fazer que eu depois coloco no combobox separado só que eu quero juntar tudo em um só tem como?

```
$sqlq = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM tbl_tipo ORDER BY tipo ASC");
$sqlq ->execute();
$sqlqu = $pdo->prepare("SELECT cod_empresa,razao_social FROM tbl_empresa ORDER by razao_social ASC");
$sqlqu ->execute();
$sqlque = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM tbl_pessoa_fisica ORDER BY nome ASC");
$sqlque ->execute();
$sqlquer = $pdo->prepare("SELECT cod_empregado,nome FROM tbl_empregado ORDER BY nome ASC");
$sqlque ->execute();
```

Tipo assim

```
$sqlquery = $pdo->prepare("SELECT tipo.*, empresa.*, pessoa.*, empregado.* FROM tbl_tipo tipo tbl_empresa empresa tbl_pessoafisica pessoa tbl_empregado empregado")
```

E depois fazer aquele `$linha->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)`

Comment: Cara, você vai procurar por inner join, left join, right join e coisas do tipo

Comment: Você quer um select para cada tabela e quer que retorne os dados de todas ou quer pegar dados especificos que tenham relação na outra tabela?

Comment: E quando você rodar `->execute()`, o que vai ser retornado? E se a quantidade de linhas retornadas por cada `select` não for a mesma?

Answer (score 1):

Para o poder interiorizar, existe uma forma mais simples de executar esses sql todos de uma forma mais simples sem uso de pdo mas ficará ao seu criterio:

```
$sql = ("SELECT * FROM tbl_tipo ORDER BY tipo ASC"); 
$sql .=("SELECT cod_empresa,razao_social FROM tbl_empresa ORDER by razao_social ASC");
$sql .=("SELECT * FROM tbl_pessoa_fisica ORDER BY nome ASC");
$sql .=("SELECT cod_empregado,nome FROM tbl_empregado ORDER BY nome ASC"); 
 $result=mysqli_multi_query($conn, $sql);
```

Se quer os dados todos como tem apresentado exemplo, será assim:

```
$sqlquery = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM tbl_tipo tipo, tbl_empresa empresa, tbl_pessoafisica pessoa, tbl_empregado empregado")
```

Caso pretenda dados especificos em que existe ligação de tabelas através de `FK`, então o ideal será usar INNER JOIN, LEFT JOIN, RIGHT JOIN, FULL OUTER JOIN, ETC.

Tem ai uma imagem com alguns exemplos.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Espero ter ajudado.

Answer (score 0):

AMIGÃO RS VAMOS LÁ!

Correto mesmo seria suas tabelas terem relacionamentos entre si... Porém acredito que vc não tenha pensado nisso antes, mas vou tentar te ajudar...

O ideal é vc criar uma CLASSE FUNCIONARIO como exemplo:

```
class Funcionario{

  private $nome;
  private $tipo; 
  private $empresa;
  private $codEmpresa;
  private $razaoSocial; 
  //ENTRE OUTROS PARAMETROS
}
```

Criaria uma classe FuncionarioDAO, implementaria 4 métodos correspondente aos seus 4 SELECTS e com os dados retornados popularia um OBJETO Funcionario